# How can I test my published Google Play app if it's not available in my country?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, publishing

I've just published an app on Google Play, and I want to make sure that it's working for real users.  However, I don't want it to be available in my country.  How can I test my app?

My goal is to make sure that the process of downloading the app from the store, running it, and using in app purchases, etc, is all working fine.

When I try to download the app, of course Google Play tells me that it's not available in my country.  I've tried uploading a version of the app to Google Play as a Beta version, and adding myself as a Beta tester, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I see two obvious solutions:

1. Make the app be available in your country just for a minute while
   you would download it to your device.
2. Use a proxy server to access
   the Internet located in the appropriate country. I consider Google
   Play will think that's your actual location.